# How do I use Win32's GetRawInputDeviceList in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, winapi

I'm trying to use the [`GetRawInputDeviceList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist) function in Go and I keep getting the following error:

`The parameter is incorrect.`

Per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist): the first parameter needs to be an array of [`RAWINPUTDEVICELIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevicelist) structures for the devices attached to the system. I don't quite understand what combination of `unsafe.Pointer`, pointer arithmetic(?), and other things I need to do in order to get this to work correctly.

I found [this Medium article](https://medium.com/jettech/breaking-all-the-rules-using-go-to-call-windows-api-2cbfd8c79724) that offers some guidance, but it's not directly applicable to my use case. I don't have enough experience working with pointers and manual memory management to apply it to my problem. I don't know how to translate [this C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457919/5094134) to Go, and I got so desperate that I tried to convert [a working VBA solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36240342/5094134) to Go with no success.

**I have two questions regarding this matter:**

1. How do I convert an array of structs in Go to the appropriate type expected for a Windows API call?
2. How do I convert the result of the Windows API call back to an array of structs with populated data?

## Environment

Here's my system/language details:

- macOS Mojave v10.14.6
- Go v1.10.7 (required to run executables on Windows XP)

I'm targeting Windows XP, so I run the following command to compile it:

```
env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go1.10.7 build -o example.exe example.go
```

## Code

Here's the code I'm trying to get working. I'm not doing anything with `devices` yet, but the goal would be to use the handle (`DeviceHandle` from `rawInputDeviceList`) to get information about the input device.

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "syscall"
  "unsafe"
)

// RAWINPUTDEVICELIST structure
type rawInputDeviceList struct {
  DeviceHandle uintptr
  Type         uint32
}

var (
  user32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
  getRawInputDeviceListProc = user32.NewProc("GetRawInputDeviceList")
)

func main() {
  dl := rawInputDeviceList{}
  size := uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(dl))

  // First I determine how many input devices are on the system, which
  // gets assigned to `devCount`
  var devCount uint32
  _ = getRawInputDeviceList(nil, &devCount, size)

  if devCount > 0 {
    size = size * devCount
    devices := make([]rawInputDeviceList, size) // <- This is definitely wrong

    for i := 0; i < int(devCount); i++ {
      devices[i] = rawInputDeviceList{}
    }

    // Here is where I get the "The parameter is incorrect." error:
    err := getRawInputDeviceList(&devices, &devCount, size)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
    }
  }
}

// Enumerates the raw input devices attached to the system.
func getRawInputDeviceList(
  rawInputDeviceList *[]rawInputDeviceList, // <- This is probably wrong
  numDevices *uint32,
  size uint32,
) error {
  _, _, err := getRawInputDeviceListProc.Call(
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(rawInputDeviceList)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(numDevices)),
    uintptr(size))
  if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
    return err
  }

  return nil
}
```

Comment: You just need to treat it as a `GetRawInputDeviceList` pointer, and the `size` you pass the second time  has been changed with `size = size * devcount` instead of `sizeof (GetRawInputDeviceList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error is cause by the last parameter: `cbSize`, According to the document, it should always be set to size of `RAWINPUTDEVICELIST`.

Then you will pass the compiler but still get the runtime error. because you have passed a pointer of array.

The following code works for me:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "syscall"
  "unsafe"
)

// RAWINPUTDEVICELIST structure
type rawInputDeviceList struct {
  DeviceHandle uintptr
  Type         uint32
}

var (
  user32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
  getRawInputDeviceListProc = user32.NewProc("GetRawInputDeviceList")
)

func main() {
  dl := rawInputDeviceList{}
  size := uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(dl))

  // First I determine how many input devices are on the system, which
  // gets assigned to `devCount`
  var devCount uint32
  _ = getRawInputDeviceList(nil, &devCount, size)

  if devCount > 0 {
    devices := make([]rawInputDeviceList, size * devCount) // <- This is definitely wrong

    for i := 0; i < int(devCount); i++ {
      devices[i] = rawInputDeviceList{}
    }

    // Here is where I get the "The parameter is incorrect." error:
    err := getRawInputDeviceList(&devices[0], &devCount, size)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < int(devCount); i++ {
      fmt.Printf("Type: %v", devices[i].Type)
    }

  }
}

// Enumerates the raw input devices attached to the system.
func getRawInputDeviceList(
  rawInputDeviceList *rawInputDeviceList, // <- This is probably wrong
  numDevices *uint32,
  size uint32,
) error {
  _, _, err := getRawInputDeviceListProc.Call(
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(rawInputDeviceList)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(numDevices)),
    uintptr(size))
  if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
    return err
  }

  return nil
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Mike did this does help your issue?

Comment: Hi @drake-wu-msft, I apologize for the delayed response. I just tried your solution and it worked. Thank you so much for your help!