# How to get a list of available joystick ids in Go

Tags: go, cross-platform, joystick, gamepad

I'm trying to find joystick state in a cross platform way - developing on windows - using Golang.  I'm currently looking to use the joystick API at https://github.com/0xcafed00d/joystick

However, for Go on windows, I don't know how to find the id that I need for `joystick.Open(joy_id)`.

Does anyone know of a Go API that allows me to get a list of currently plugged in joysticks/gamepads so I can iterate through their ids?  I don't mind if this is just for Windows.  **N.B. I'm happy to use standard windows libraries or Go packages, but don't want to have to install anything, e.g. SDL 2, since the target users are non technical.**

*Note 2: I've originally did this with the browser Gamepad API - but the gamepad API is suspended when the browser window is in the background/minimized.*

Comment: maybe that will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662743/how-do-i-use-win32s-getrawinputdevicelist-in-go